# Send emails to inactive users on WordPress site using MailChimp

Tags: php, wordpress, email, mailchimp

Is there any solution to send email notifications to inactive users?

- I can get list of inactive users in server side. (cronjob + SQL query
  to DB)
- I can subscribe users to some subscription. //
  `$mc4wpApi->subscribe($list_id, $email);`

But I don't need new subscription list. I need only once event.
I've read about triggers, automations in MailChimp documentation. But i'm not sure, what I need for my goal.

**I need just send emails notifications to all users that were inactive for last N-days** (7, 14 or 28-days).

I don't know, how to make this correctly. Is it possible witch MailChimp eventually?

Do I need make call to API like this (*"/automations/8b1a31b1/emails/5198414/queue"*) ?
But it will send emails to all users from list, as I can see.

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. It's my second time, when I must use MailChimp and I'm not adept here at all. Sorry)

Comment: Why don't you make a query to get all the inactive users emails from WordPress and then import those mails in MailChimp?

Comment: Is this a one-time event or something that happens regularly?

Comment: Checking for inactive users happens regularry (every day). And lists of inactive users (inactive for 7, 14 and 28 day) for each day may be different.

Comment: How can I import list of inactive users into MailChimp? And how can I synchronize these lists each day?